# HTML charset and encoding

Tags: encoding, localization, resourcebundle

I need to build an JSP application that will be localized to non-latin languages.  The JSP page contains tags that retrieve some display elements from a database (MySQL) and others from a resource bundle (properties file whose contents are written in Unicode and I also tried UTF-8).

The prolem, I believe, is that the string returned from the resource bundle seems to place each byte of the unicode/UTF-8 code-point in its own string character.  For example /u0620 occupies two characters in the returned string, the first character has 0x06 and the second character has 0x20.  Strings retrieved from the resource bundle are double in size.

Is my problem in the properties file itself or is it in the resourceBundle ?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use UTF-8, then a UTF-8 character actually *IS* 2 bytes. Whether the programming language handles it as two bytes or one character shouldn't be important for your actual code.

Also, avoid using UTF-16 or other forms of Unicode. UTF-8 is the only "proper" way to do things nowadays.

Also, as bmargulies pointed out, you may want to use `pageEncoding="utf-8"`

Comment: Yes, I realize that. The problem turned out to be in the encoding of my properties file. It needed to be in escaped-unicode (/uxxxx), not unicode characters.  When I had pure unicode characters in my properties file the resource bundle doubled up the characters in my string, each character holding one half of the unicode/UTF-8 code point. But when I changed the file to have only ascii characters that represent the escaped unicode/UTF-8 code points, the resourceBundle read the file properly.